# In standard RDP security, where the modulus coming from?

Tags: windows, certificate, rsa, packet, rdp

I'm currently working on old system that uses RDP. According to [4.1.4 Server MCS Connect Response PDU with GCC Conference Create Response described in [MS-RDPBCGR]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rdpbcgr/d23f7725-876c-48d4-9e41-8288896a19d3), packet is containing modulus, which should be part of RSA key. And I need to know where this came from because I need to decrypt some RDP packets stored as log.

First thing I've done is looking up certificates by using `mmc`. But there was no certificate matching with modulus. Even if I issued new self-signed certificate, there was no luck. Modulus is not changing by it.

More specifically, this is response packet from testing server(VM) containing modulus.

```
0000: 03 00 02 15 02 f0 80 7f 66 82 02 09 0a 01 00 02 | ......f......
0016: 01 00 30 1a 02 01 22 02 01 03 02 01 00 02 01 01 | ..0...".........
0032: 02 01 00 02 01 01 02 03 00 ff f8 02 01 02 04 82 | .............
0048: 01 e3 00 05 00 14 7c 00 01 2a 14 76 0a 01 01 00 | .....|..*.v....
0064: 01 c0 00 4d 63 44 6e 81 cc 01 0c 10 00 0c 00 08 | ..McDn.......
0080: 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 03 0c 10 00 eb 03 04 | ...............
0096: 00 ec 03 ed 03 ee 03 ef 03 02 0c ac 01 02 00 00 | ...........
0112: 00 02 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 78 01 00 00 bb e4 de | ..... ...x...
0128: 58 1a 05 8f 26 89 f8 94 0b 88 d4 79 d4 00 ac bf | X..&.y.
0144: e0 07 72 3a e5 9b 17 7f 17 d6 18 92 7f 01 00 00 | .r:........
0160: 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 06 00 1c 01 52 53 41 | .............RSA
0176: 31 08 01 00 00 00 08 00 00 ff 00 00 00 01 00 01 | 1..............
0192: 00 2d 13 bc 1d a9 5b c8 60 9b be 66 61 ab 09 13 | .-..[`fa..
0208: 4e 0a 1f 64 27 72 df 92 18 42 ea 2c 05 5d 0d a7 | N..d'r..B,.].
0224: f7 06 51 5d 22 2e 4a fa 03 c5 8d 52 47 7c fa 13 | .Q]".J..RG|.
0240: ec dd bb 81 15 50 4b b3 f0 7b e4 75 0e e6 0d b5 | ..PK{u..
0256: ab d2 4a 9c ab f6 8c 83 a3 53 0b 87 b1 07 fc 0f | JS...
0272: 29 12 f4 c8 18 fb 9f 6d 29 10 34 af 34 d0 ca 8d | )..m).44.
0288: 48 a9 2e 9e 85 9a 39 d6 6c be cb f3 36 75 60 a5 | H.9l6u`
0304: 56 a5 a3 f5 b0 6f af c3 8e 5b 03 11 e4 27 27 bf | Vo.[..''
0320: a0 05 51 aa f1 8d 84 11 53 43 59 b8 83 4f f2 2d | .Q.SCYO-
0336: 40 44 b1 f9 5a 5b e6 2d 32 e4 d8 ef 2a 5a f8 01 | @DZ[-2*Z.
0352: 08 7a 68 a0 05 e2 5b fe 50 b5 38 cd a6 f0 ef e0 | .zh.[P8.
0368: c4 6f 4e f3 f1 9d 0a 89 ce 79 4e 3d 6f e3 a2 b3 | oN.yN=o.
0384: c7 fd dc b2 d8 c6 76 e8 79 67 ca fe 71 5d a5 3d | .vygq]=
0400: d3 40 c4 a4 28 5c 11 b7 2a 51 cd 65 e4 5f fc 2a | @.(\.*Qe_*
0416: bf 4c b1 e0 96 89 05 4b c6 72 1a 62 eb a2 51 0d | L.Kr.bQ.
0432: 45 2f 23 27 67 0e a8 c6 12 ed 81 ee 09 58 10 02 | E/#'g...X..
0448: b2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 48 00 e9 95 02 | ..........H..
0464: 48 e7 84 d6 fc 60 cd 29 b2 91 7c f4 e8 b4 36 5d | H`)|6]
0480: e5 5e b4 90 d4 d4 5d 6a a1 42 69 c6 4e 5c 87 f2 | ^]jBiN\
0496: 0a cd 86 f5 64 e3 4d 61 60 0a 17 c2 f8 94 93 83 | ..dMa`..
0512: cf 23 7d c4 a3 07 ad f0 b6 bc 1a b1 00 00 00 00 | #}.......
0528: 00 00 00 00 00                                  | .....
```

Public exponent is `01 00 01 00`, modulus is `2d 13 bc 1d ... 58 10 02 b2` with additional 8 bytes of zero-padding.

After that, if I know what private exponent is, then I can decrypt [Client Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rdpbcgr/b6075470-bbdd-465a-b6d9-ef15941ae358) and generate session key.

But as I've mentioned, I can't find where modulus is coming from. How can I obtain RSA key(or certificate, so I can use [Mimikatz](https://github.com/ParrotSec/mimikatz)) for it?

---

#### Edit

I found there is [Proprietary Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rdpbcgr/8adb6a70-6e3e-4375-adcf-a6ca2db2a7b8). It seems this is what I need to find, but I still don't know where it is.

---

#### Edit: I came across the Proprietary Certificate, but where is private key?

It was located at registry `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\RCM` and is just public key BLOB. Still need to find private key...

Currently I'm looking into registry key `Secrets` under `RCM`, but I don't know what are these values right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this because I found public key BLOB at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\RCM\Certificate` from registry though I don't know what private key is.